# Ingesting source files from other open source project into mine

Tags: copyright, licensing, open-source-software

I am publishing an open-source code project under the [MIT-style license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/). I have the full notice in the `LICENSE` file of the source repository.

I want to take a whole file from another open-source project licensed under [the Apache 2.0 license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache-2.0/). The two licenses are commonly regarded as compatible. If that matters, the code of the file will be part of test harness, not distributed with the binary package compiled from my sources, but rather used at compile time only. But the code should still be published as part of the project, e. g. on GitHub.

How should I reflect the other project copyright? Is retaining a copyright notice at the beginning of the ingested file enough? Or should I also mention "Copyright (c) that_other_project" somewhere else, and where if so?

Comment: If you're using open source software in your toolset but not redistributing it, it is not necessary to license it to your users.

Comment: @phoog: thank you. I am not redistributing this code in the binary package, but am publishing a copy on GitHub. I do not understand if that is legally a redistribution or not.

Comment: in that case I'm glad I posted this as a comment rather than an answer.  I will be interested to see what your question yields.

Comment: @phoog: I added a clarification to my question, glad that you spotted it might be unclear!

Comment: @kkm publishing code on github is redistribution. You do have to comply with the licence terms of the software you have taken code from.

Comment: @bdsi: Yes, I am sure I have to. *What* do I need to do to comply is exactly my original question.